# Installing rosdep performance improvements

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using docker run.sh cmd run build ros ci packages.
On docker file I have

```
  RUN rosdep init
  RUN rosdep fix-permissions
```

On entry point run

```
rosdep update
```

On cmd run.sh I run

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

The rosdep command install all ros dependencies based on a cloned git repo with ros packages and takes about 10 minutes on standard laptop with ~60Mb/s connection speed.

Can you suggest faster way of doing the same? Assuming the dependencies of the cloned repo can be changed (added or removed) on every clone.

Thanks a lot,
Tal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335738/installing-rosdep-performance-improvements/) by [Tal Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/36509/tal-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-20**:
What are the specs of the machine you are running this on? Does it have an SSD, or a spinning disk?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-20**:\

> ```
> RUN rosdep fix-permissions
> ```

there's no point in running this from within a Docker `build` sequence. Unless you run it after switching to a non-`root` user.

**Comment by [Tal Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/36509/tal-ma/) on 2019-10-20**:
Ok.
My laptop is quite new and has SSD Disk with 12 8th gen i7 CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Connection speed depends on the server too. You might have a fast connection but if those packages are hosted on servers which are slow, you don't have anything to do.

You can use a mirror for your ros packages, example here: [How do I set up a ROS mirror?](https://answers.ros.org/question/9163/how-do-i-set-up-a-ros-mirror/)

(Also you can use [an existing mirror depending on your location](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) during ROS installation, if you see that one of these mirrors will be as fast as your custom mirror)

You can try changing your Ubuntu update servers to install packages faster,
[example here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main).

And also you can try to host those dependency repositories on a mirror server which you'd access faster if this is the case.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-20**:
re: package mirror: running a local one *could* speed things up, but it may also be a lot of work/overhead. Perhaps OP could already benefit from using an [existing mirror](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) that is (geographically) closer to him/her.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-10-20**:
True, forgot to mention. Updating my answer now. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-10-20**:
Currently I don't have an access to a testing environment, from the question, I assumed that `rosdep` is able to clone repositories too. I didn't see such functionality before. Is it available?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-20**:
No. `rosdep` does not deal with source dependencies. It only installs dependencies resolvable through package managers (see #q215059 for a general overview of what it does).

This is not entirely true btw, as something called "rosdep manifests" is still supported, but I would not use those (see #q255238).

For source-based dependencies, use `wstool` or `vcstool`.